# Fatal error: require_once() (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear')

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project,i am getting an error in require_once(or even in require)

```
Warning: require_once(C:/wamp/www/MyFiles/MyProject/includes/db_config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\MyFiles\MyProject\includes\autoloads.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/MyFiles/MyProject/includes/db_config.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\MyFiles\MyProject\includes\autoloads.php on line 9
```

this is how i am including the file

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//config..
require_once($root . '/MyFiles/MyProject/includes/db_config.php');
```

i have tried using

```
echo $root . '/MyFiles/MyProject/includes/db_config.php';
```

It is printing URL properly

ie  `C:\wamp\www\MyFiles\MyProject\includes\db_config.php`

I am using WAMP server 5 autload.php and db_config.php are in same folder

Comment: are you **sure** the file (`db_config.php`) is in that destination?

Comment: Yes the file is located at the same path

Comment: Do i've to make any configuration in PHP.ini?

Comment: The codez never lies. It can't be.

Comment: Well if it really is printing `C:\wamp\www\MyFiles\MyProject\includes\db_config.php` then no.

Comment: It is located on the same path as it is printing, even i can open it on dreamweaver

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_exists($root . '/MyFiles/MyProject/includes/db_config.php'))` say?

Comment: your are writing this code  in `autoload.php` which is already in that path. so dont use `$root`

Comment: show the other lines of `autoload.php`. you must define included path in that file.

Comment: in my autoload i am including all files which are required in my project

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this require construction

   `require 'file';`
2. ..or this root settings

   `$root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

   ---

> ***update***
>   use virtual host

---

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi Have you tried to remove spaces in path?

Answer (score 0):

Is the file readable?

Try this:

```
<?php
echo "Does file exist?". file_exists($file) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo "Is it readable?".is_readable($file) ? 'true' : 'false';
require_once $file;
```

You can also use path relative to the file you're in, instead of relying on the DOCUMENT_ROOT string:

```
<?php
$root = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Additionally, the directory separate in windows is by default \, not / (alltough / should resolve aswell, even for require). There's a predefined constant you could use, just to make sure it's compatible everywhere though:

```
require_once($root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'MyFiles' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'MyProject' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'includes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'db_config.php';
```

Also, if you are using APC cache, you can attempt to restart it, if there's a stale cache of the file. (E.G filemtime is incorrect)

Comment: Thanks for reply Jon,Both statements are printing true but reuquire_once of this code giving same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Double check if the file exists on the server. If you can't for whatever reason, this will do it:

```
if(file_exists($myFile)){
echo"The file is there";
}//end of file exists
else{
echo"the file does NOT exist....fool";
}//end of else - the file is not there
```

That's the only problem I can think of - the file is not where it should be... Try the above and keep me updated.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well be a problem with the directory separator being diffrent on linux and windows machines.
Maybe try using the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of hardcoded separators?

Comment: And by the way. If you say `echo $root . '/MyFiles/MyProject/includes/db_config.php';` in your code and it echoes `C:\wamp\www\MyFiles\MyProject\includes\db_config.php` I think there might be something wrong with your slashes and backslashes

Answer (score 0):

check the existence of file, if exists, check the permission of file.